# Set frame of UIVIew so its not hidden by navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I am programmatically pushing to a view controller where I load a web view, and I set the web view like this

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.url]];
[self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 600);
self.webView.delegate = self;
```

And it looks good, I set it the y to 64 so that it is below the nav bar, but then when I tap the web view or zoom the web view moves down another 64 points?

Why does this happen? But if I set the web view to this at the beginning `self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 600);`, then until I tap the webivew part of it is hidden by the nav bar.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Did you try `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;` if it's for iOS 7 and above

Comment: @Aladin I want the nav bar to be there, I just want the web view to be below it

Comment: Yes it should solve the issue

Comment: @Aladin wow that worked Ive been trying to solve this for hours what does `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;` do?

Comment: I ment to write `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` not  `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;` that helps to get an opaque UINavigationBar on iOS 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars)

> The extended edges to use for the layout.
>        @property(nonatomic, assign) UIRectEdge edgesForExtendedLayout

in your `viewDidLoad` method :

```
 if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) {
   self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone; 
}
```